# Error on constructor while extending class

Tags: java, constructor, arguments, extend, extends

I am a beginner in java and during coding, i faced an issue which is not easy to understand for me. My question is "Write a class with a method to find the area of a rectangle. Create a subclass to find the volume of a rectangular shaped box." The error i am facing is below. I wrote this code for the same:-

```
class Rectangle
{
    public int w;
    public int h;

    public Rectangle(int width, int height)
    {
        w=width;
        h=height;
    }
    public void area()
    {
        int area=w*h;
        System.out.println("Area of Rectangle : "+area);
    }
}
class RectangleBox extends Rectangle
{
    int d;
    public RectangleBox(int width, int height, int depth)
    {
        d=depth;
        w=width;
        h=height;   

    }
    public void volume()
    {
        int volume=w*h*d;
        System.out.println("Volume of Rectangle : "+volume);
    }
}
class programm8
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(10,20);
    RectangleBox rb = new RectangleBox(4,5,6);
    r.area();
    rb.volume();
    }
}
```

> Error:(23, 5) java: constructor Rectangle in class code.Rectangle
>   cannot be applied to given types;   required: int,int   found: no
>   arguments   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Thanks to everyone who invested their precious time to answer my question. Thanks a lot guys..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a child object firstly a parent constructor works. In this example when you create a RectangleBox object, firstly Rectangle constructor works after that RectangleBox constructor works. So, your child constructor have to call a parent constructor.

Normally if you have default constructors for parent and child classes, child default constructor calls parent default constructor. But you dont have default constructors because of this RectangleBox constructor have to call a Rectangle constructor. And for calling a parent contructor you have to use `super` keyword. 
And then your code:

```
public Rectangle(int width, int height)
    {
        w=width;
        h=height;
    }

public RectangleBox(int width, int height, int depth)
    {
        super(width, width)
        h=height;   

    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir to invest your precious time to answer my question. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public RectangleBox(int width, int height, int depth)
    {
        d=depth;
        w=width;
        h=height;   

    }
```

The very first thing this constructor does, is call the constructor of the parent class with the same parameters (unless you specifically tell your constructor to call another one), which would be:

```
public Rectangle(int width, int height, int depth)
    {
        w=width;
        h=height;
    }
```

This constructor doesn't exist. You'll need to manually call your parent constructor with the appropriate parameters, like this:

```
public RectangleBox(int width, int height, int depth)
    {
        super(width, height);
        d=depth;    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sir to invest your precious time to answer my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You do need to call a constructor of super class at first:

```
class RectangleBox extends Rectangle
{
int d;
public RectangleBox(int width, int height, int depth)
{
    super(width, height);
    d=depth;

}
public void volume()
{
    int volume=w*h*d;
    System.out.println("Volume of Rectangle : "+volume);
}
}
```

Comment: actually, that is being called, that's the problem. you may want to re-word your answer to "you need to call the correct constructor of your super class first"

Comment: Thank you sir to invest your precious time to answer my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is related to the subject; Invoking Superclass Constructor

You can search with that title for detailed information.

If a class is inheriting any properties from another class, the subclass has to invoke its parent class constructor. If the parent's class constructor has no argument java invokes it by itself you don't have to do anything. But in your case Rectangle class has the constructor with the arguments "width" and "height". Therefore when you write the constructor for subclass first thing you need to do is invoking parent class'. When you want to call a parameterized constructor of the superclass, you need to use the super keyword as shown below.

```
 public RectangleBox(int width, int height, int depth)
{   
    super(width, height);
    d=depth;
    w=width;
    h=height;   

}
```

Comment: Thank you sir to invest your precious time to answer my question. :)